# Multiplying Columns Efficiently in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to multiply a set of columns `s_cols` with two other columns `b`, `c`.

So far, I was doing

```
s_cols = ['t070101', 't070102', 't070103', 't070104', 't070105', 't070199', 't070201', 't070299']
dfNew = df[s_cols]*df[`c`]*df[`b`]
```

but that operation sucked all the 16GB of memory off my system and crashed my OSX - the table has `148000` rows.

What should I do instead? I guess applying row-wise requires less active memory, but it seems to be less inefficient than a vectorized operation.

The table:

```
                             b  TELFS  t070101  t070102  t070103  t070104  \
TUCASEID                                                                    
20030100013280  8155462.672158      2        0        0        0        0   
20030100013344  1735322.527819      1        0        0        0        0   
20030100013352  3830527.482672      2       60        0        0        0   
20030100013848  6622022.995205      4        0        0        0        0   
20030100014165  3068387.344956      1        0        0        0        0   

                t070105  t070199  t070201  t070299   \
TUCASEID                                                              
20030100013280        0        0        0        0  
20030100013344        0        0        0        0  
20030100013352        0        0        0        0  
20030100013848        0        0        0        0  
20030100014165        0        0        0           

                         c  
TUCASEID                               
20030100013280          31  
20030100013344          31  
20030100013352          31  
20030100013848          31  
20030100014165          31
```

**UPDATE**

The issue seems to be using `df[s_cols]`. Multiplication of a single column happens instantly, but already multiplying `df[['t070101', 't070102']]` was taking long enough that I was afraid of my system crashing again and preemptively shut down the Python process.

Comment: Does it succeed if you break the operation into 2 steps? so `t = df[`c`]*df[`b`]  dfNew = df[s_cols] * t`

Comment: to be honest I don't expect the above to be any different, what version of numpy and pandas are you using?

Comment: @EdChum: `1.9.1` and `0.15.0`. Yes, the above was no different.

Comment: I would expect this to just work, try upgrading pandas and give it another go

Comment: @EdChum, nope - still freezingly cold here. I'm using PyCharm, perhaps this could be a reason?

Comment: could be, I use ipython, no experience with pycharm

Comment: Have you tried df[s_cols].multiply(df[`c`].multiply(df[`b`]))?

Comment: @user4589964 didn't help either.

Comment: @EdChum: Tried upgrading to `4.0`, didn't help. Even if the code should work, it doesn't do it here. I'm still looking for a workaround.

Comment: How many columns is your s_cols list?  I tried a simple 150k x 100 dataframe and had no problem.

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(150000,100)) * pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(150000)) * pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(150000))

Comment: @user4589964 It doesn't seem to be the number of columns, rather the way I am slicing the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you actually want to do something like the following:

```
In [11]: cols = ['a', 'b']

In [12]: df1
Out[12]:
   a  b  c   d
0  1  4  1   4
1  2  5  2  10
2  3  6  3  18

In [13]: df1[cols].multiply(df1['c'] * df1['d'], axis=0)
Out[13]:
     a    b
0    4   16
1   40  100
2  162  324
```

As you can see your code with this example: the index is prepended to the columns (so the size of the DataFrame is N^2 in the length, potentially that would cause memory error / slowdown):

```
In [21]: df1[cols] * df1['c'] * df1['d']
Out[21]:
    0   1   2   a   b
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

*Aside: you should put the brackets here to ensure the RHS is calculated first.*

---

Another option for problems like this is to use numexpr, see [enhancing performance with eval](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#enhancingperf-eval) section of the pandas docs. However I don't think there is (currently) support for multiple assignment, so in this case it wouldn't help - nonetheless it is worthwhile reading.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is apparently caused by `pandas`' suboptimal handling of the data frame slicing `df[s_cols]`.

If instead I do

```
for col in s_cols:
    df[col] = df[col].multiply(df.monthDays * df.TUFNWGTP)
```

the operation is done almost instantly.